# Sidekiq superworker namespace issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have this code inside a rails engine:

```
Superworker.create(:AJob, :a_id, :data) do
  AWorker :a_id, :data do
    parallel do
      BWorker :a_id, :data
      CWorker :a_id, :data
      DWorker :a_id, :data
    end
    EWorker :a_id, :data
  end
end
```

The problem I'm facing is that the workers are under the engine namespace and Superworker factory does not understand MyEngine::AWorker notation, how can this be solved?
Workers path was added to the autoload path using:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..')
    config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path(File.join(ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT, 'app', 'workers', 'my_engine'))

    require File.expand_path(File.join(ENGINE_RAILS_ROOT, 'app', 'jobs', 'superworkers'))
  end
end
```

What might be the problem?

UPDATE1: 
When trying to add namespaces to workers like this:

```
Superworker.create(:AJob, :a_id, :data) do
      MyEngine::AWorker :a_id, :data do
        parallel do
          MyEngine::BWorker :a_id, :data
          MyEngine::CWorker :a_id, :data
          MyEngine::DWorker :a_id, :data
        end
        MyEngine::EWorker :a_id, :data
      end
    end
```

I get the following:

```
<top (required)>': undefined method `AWorker' for MyEngine:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sidekiq-superworker-0.1.8/lib/sidekiq/superworker/dsl_parser.rb:15:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sidekiq-superworker-0.1.8/lib/sidekiq/superworker/dsl_parser.rb:15:in `block in block_to_nested_hash'
```

Comment: `does not understand MyEngine::AWorker notation` - so what is the error?Can you clarify why they do not understand Engine notation.

Comment: @zishe Check the update, I'm presuming that superworker gem is trying to use it as Class.method instead of Module::Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed with https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker/issues/23 details. It was due to a sidekiq-superworker convetion on namespaces which needs to be set using MyModule__MyWorker syntax